# How can I set different colors for dot displayed in line chart in Ngx-charts in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, charts, ngx-charts

I want to use line chart of Ngx-chart library. But I am not able to change the color of the dots which are displayed on the line.

Hence How can I change those colors used for dots or provide own colors for dots in Ngx-chart Line chart?

In line-chart.html file

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      [autoScale]="autoScale"
      [timeline]="timeline"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

and in line-chart.ts file configuration of chart will be look like

```
 multi: any[] = [
  {
    name: 'Cyan',
    series: [
      {
        name: 5,
        value: 2650
      },
      {
        name: 10,
        value: 2800      },
      {
        name: 15,
        value: 2000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Yellow',
    series: [
      {
        name: 5,
        value: 2500
      },
      {
        name: 10,
        value: 3100
      },
      {
        name: 15,
        value: 2350
      }
    ]
  }
];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Number';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Color Value';
  timeline = true;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

In above code's output it shows 2 lines in the chart but I want to make a single line like for every student there will be a chart denoting marks of student so there will be a single line in the chart in which dots will be displayed in different colors according to marks category like 
for marks >50 color of dots = green
    marks >70 color of dots = pink and like wise.

Comment: please share code what you have done so far

Comment: I have added simple configuration for charts in question